# What is the easiest and efficient way to get positive or negative combinations of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Consider the following simple case:

```
list={1,2,2};
Subsets[{Splice[list],Splice[-list]},{1,Length@list}]
```

This produces the following combinations:

{{1}, {2}, {2}, {-1}, {-2}, {-2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, -1}, {1, -2}, {1, -2}, {2, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, -2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, -2}, {2, -2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -2}, {-2, -2}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, -1}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -1}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {1, -2, -2}, {2, 2, -1}, {2, 2, -2}, {2, 2, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {-1, -2, -2}}

The problem I am trying to solve requires me to have all possible combinations of `list` but in any given combination, if an entry appears then it either appears as positive or negative and not both.

So for example `{2, -2, -2}` is invalid since a given `2` should appear as positive or negative but here there are three `2`s appearing even though the original `list` had two `2`s.

Also, I am looking for an efficient way to generate the required combination.

Comment: Does `tal = Lookup[Counts[list], Union[list], 0]; Select[Subsets[{Splice[list], Splice[-list]}, {1, Length[list]}], And @@ Thread[Lookup[Counts[Abs[#]], Union[list], 0] <= tal] &]` do what you want?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it seems to be producing the correct result for the cases I tested. But is there a way to directly produce this outcome instead of first finding all combinations and then filtering the relevant ones?

Comment: I am not sure, and that's why I left a comment and not an answer. I agree it can quickly get combinatorically prohibitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 2};
result = Subsets[{Splice[list], Splice[-list]}, {1, Length@list}]
GroupBy[result, Length[Intersection[#, -#]] < 1 &]
```

```
<|True -> {{1}, {2}, {2}, {-1}, {-2}, {-2}, {1, 2}, {1, 
    2}, {1, -2}, {1, -2}, {2, 
    2}, {2, -1}, {2, -1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -2}, {-2, -2}, {1, 2, 
    2}, {1, -2, -2}, {2, 2, -1}, {-1, -2, -2}}, 
 False -> {{1, -1}, {2, -2}, {2, -2}, {2, -2}, {2, -2}, {1, 
    2, -1}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, -1}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 
    2, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {2, 2, -2}, {2, 
    2, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {2, \
-1, -2}, {2, -2, -2}}|>
```

Comment: Your `GroupBy`'s condition is correctly discarding things like `{1,2,-1}` which is ok since we can't have more than one `1`s but it is also incorrectly discarding `{1,2,-2}` which is not correct since the original list does allow for two `2`s.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to construct the list directly:

```
list = {1,2,2};

Splice[Curry[Times][#] /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, Length@#]]& /@
  DeleteDuplicates@Subsets[list, {1,Length@list}]

(*
{{1},{-1},{2},{-2},
 {1,2},{1,-2},{-1,2},{-1,-2},{2,2},{2,-2},{-2,2},{-2,-2},
 {1,2,2},{1,2,-2},{1,-2,2},{1,-2,-2},{-1,2,2},{-1,2,-2},{-1,-2,2},{-1,-2,-2}}
*)
```

If the input list can contain elements that are equal but with opposite signs, then `DeleteDuplicates` ought to be replaced by `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Abs]`.

On the other hand, if it is desirable to retain repeated result elements in those cases where an input element is repeated (e.g. `2` in the example), then remove `DeleteDuplicates@` altogether:

```
Splice[Curry[Times][#] /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, Length@#]]& /@
  Subsets[list, {1,Length@list}]

(*
{{1},{-1},{2},{-2},{2},{-2},
 {1,2},{1,-2},{-1,2},{-1,-2},{1,2},{1,-2},{-1,2},{-1,-2},{2,2},{2,-2},{-2,2},{-2,-2},
 {1,2,2},{1,2,-2},{1,-2,2},{1,-2,-2},{-1,2,2},{-1,2,-2},{-1,-2,2},{-1,-2,-2}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply each subset by all combinations of signs:

```
result = Flatten[
    Transpose[#*Transpose@Tuples[{1, -1}, Length@#]] & /@ 
     Subsets[list, {1, Length@list}]
    , 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
result // Sort

(*
{{-2}, {-1}, {1}, {2},
 {-2, -2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, 2},
 {-1, -2, -2}, {-1, -2, 2}, {-1, 2, -2}, {-1, 2, 2}, {1, -2, -2},
   {1, -2, 2}, {1, 2, -2}, {1, 2, 2}}
*)
```

As with @WReach's answer, if you wish to retain the multiple occurrences of the same set such the two instances of `{2}`, omit `DeleteDuplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

You may construct you answer by treating each case separately.

The one element cases:

```
t1 = Subsets[list, {1}]
t2 = Subsets[-list, {1}]
```

and the two element cases:

```
t3 = Flatten[Outer[List, list, list], 1]
t4 = Flatten[Outer[List, list, -list], 1]
t5 = Flatten[Outer[List, -list, -list], 1]
```

And then combine everything:

```
Join[t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]
```